Minify CSS in Parcel dev mode
I'm trying to get Parcel to minify my CSS in dev mode, but I'm not sure it's possible.
The Parcel docs give the impression you can configure targets like this, but also mention minification only takes place for production builds. So I'm unsure I can expect this to work at all.
My config has a target defined with optimize set to true, but when I run npm run parcel it will still generate unminified CSS in the assets output directory. When I run the build script, it does get minified.
Below is what my package.json looks like. I'm not running any other plugins.
{
  "scripts": {
    "parcel": "parcel watch --target production",
    "build": "parcel build  --target production",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.12.0",
  },
  "targets": {
    "production": {
      "source" : [
        "src/css/styles.css",
        "src/js/scripts.js"
      ],
      "optimize": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "distDir": "./assets/"
    }
  }
}



nobody uses watch for prod. are you sure --target is supported with this command ?

You could try using nodemon to watch files instead of parcel watch. You could then configure nodemon to run parcel build --target production when any file changes

@Symtox Not sure if --target is support with the watch command. I've asked the same question at their github discussions section, curious to find out. I prefer minifiying in dev mode as it saves me from having to run the build command separately before I upload/commit, as it has sourcemaps anyway.

@jla Thanks for the great suggestion, I'll give that a try.

@jla Works great, I've used onchange to listen for changes and then fire parcel build when they occur. Thanks for the idea!
